# Confusing with Paths in my project

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Well, my problem is that I have many files and folders as well, and I have to include files from here and there and things went crazy !!

This is my projects folder structure:

- /catalC/inc/f1.class.php
- /catalC/adminp/addf1.php
- /catalC/css/bootstrap.min.css
- /catalC/js/ ..
- /catalC/navbar.php
- /catalC/footer.php

Actually in my file addf1.php I Have :

```
require_once('../navbar.php');
require_once('../inc/f1.class.php');
```

and the navbar.php include the css & js files.

The problem is I can't handle it, the css & js files can't  be loaded, I've read something about using dirname or realpath , but I don't know where I have to make the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

require_once($path.'navbar.php');
require_once($path.'inc/f1.class.php');  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`require_once('css/bootstrap.min.css')` // for `css` file in your `navbar.php`

`require_once ('js')` // for `js` file

Answer (score -1):

When you include a php file in another, when you open that file in your browser, all the code from the 2 files is rendered together in that one file.

So in your navbar.php file you have to include your css & js like if they are in the root.